# Writing data from for loop to one excel sheet

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I'm trying to write data from my for loop to excel file in a way that the data is in one sheet. I've been using the xlsx library but for some reason adding the APPEND = TRUE doesn't do the trick. An example of what I've been trying to do:

```
write.xlsx("Info", "results.xlsx", sheetName="Info", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)

for (i in 1:10) {
  write.xlsx(i, "results.xlsx", sheetName="datasheet",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
}
```

This only works to write the first loop results, after that I get an error telling me that there's already a sheet with the same name and it won't append the result to the sheet. How should I approach this?

Comment: Have you tried writing to different sheetName's?

Comment: @Florian My point is that I want the results to be displayed in one sheet. Using multiple sheets would be easy, but in reality my code would do a loop around 10 000 times and then push the results into a excel file, after that I need to be able to view the results easily.

Comment: Do you need to write the results 10 times to excel? Why not store it in a list or a dataframe, combine it into one data frame at the end and write is using `write.xlsx` ?

Comment: @RonakShah The way rest of the code works the best way would be to append the results after each loop - of course if there's no way of doing this I would have to try this.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried saving your output and then write it in one go (not fast!)?:

```
i0 <- NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
    i0 <- rbind(i0,i)
    }
    write.xlsx(i0, "results.xlsx", sheetName="datasheet",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)
```

see also: 
[Appending r output in a single sheet of xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429534/appending-r-output-in-a-single-sheet-of-xlsx-file)